# extjs4 - How to call an application function from a controller?

Tags: extjs

Given an application:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'APP',
    appFolder: 'app',

    funcA: function() {
        console.log('called funcA');
    },

    launch: function() {
        ...
        var funcB = function() {
            console.log('called funcB');
        }
        ...
    }
});
```

My controller can call this.application.funcA() but not funcB() within the launch method.  How can I call funcB() externally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't, as funcB is private to your launch callback, You can move it outside of the callback, just like you did `funcA`. Basically anything defined inside of a function is private to that function.

Comment: Thank you... seems kind of obvious when you put it that way.  I asked because I have some local functions in launch that create objects in my viewport (ex: tab panel).  What's the best practice to expose those objects to controllers (ex: to add tabs to panel)?